# Display only three inputs in your dropdown using selectize.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, selectize.js

I am using selectize.js for a nice dropdown, however I'm trying to show only three results when its dropped down instead of the full 20 that I've got. Thus, when a user wants to find something he needs to type unless they are one of the first three. I'm still new to Javascript and I couldn't find an answer in other questions that helped. I've put my relevant code below. Thank you so much!!

**HTML**

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :homecity, "Home Town" %><br>
   <%= f.select :homecity_id, Homecity.all.pluck(:Hometown, :id), {}, { class: "selectize1" } %>
</div>
```

**Edit.js**

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
var selectizeCallback = null;
$(".homecity-modal").on("hide.bs.modal", function(e) {
if (selectizeCallback != null) {
  selectizeCallback();
  selecitzeCallback = null;
}

$("#new_homecity").trigger("reset");
$.rails.enableFormElements($("#new_homecity"));
});
$(".selectize1").selectize({

create: function(input, callback) {
  selectizeCallback = callback;


  $(".homecity-modal").modal();
  $("#homecity_Hometown").val(input);
}
})
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

selectize takes an option parameter for "maxOptions" that provides what you want.

for example:

```
$(“.selectize1”).selectize({maxOptions: 3});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @MattMcKnight :)